# How should I enable paging in ransack results submitted via a POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kaminari, ransack

I am using Ransack to create a simple search form that will grow more complicated soon. Because I don't want to overflow the querystring, I am using POST to submit my search form. This works fine but now I want to add paging.

Looking at Kaminari, it only seems to make anchor tags (GET) - which doesn't work for me.

Can I use Kaminari and Ransack to create a search with paging and POSTed queries?

This is all the latest versions of the gems.

Answer (score 0):

You can [override the views that Kaminari uses](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#customizing-the-pagination-helper) and thusly change the anchor tags to use `method: :post`.